# Wireless solution to transfer pictures and videos to computer from iOS and Android

Tags: android, windows-7, ios, bluetooth, wireless

I am looking for a **wireless** solution (bluetooth/wifi/magic) that allows me to transfer photos and videos, *possibly* documents from my iOS and Android devices to my computer.

It should:

- all be one program
- run on Windows 7, Android 4.0+, iOS 7+
- be under £20 altogether, no subscriptions
- be *easy and simple*, ie. I open the app, select my photos, and click 'send/transfer/abracadabra, ANYTHING' and *voila*, I have them on my other device
- **be reliable** (ie. not crash every other second, like the ones below do)

I have tried:

- MoboRobo
- MoboGenie

but with multiple reinstalls and emails, I have never got either of them to work without crashing/failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for **[Send Anywhere (File Transfer)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estmob.android.sendanywhere)**, which is available (according to their description) for Android, iOS, and "PC". As the name suggests, this is not just for sharing files between devices you own, but you can share them with anyone using the app:

- Hit "Send" (generates a "6-digit one time key (OTK)")
- Give the key to the receiving party (or yourself ;)
- enter the key on the receiving end.

Now let's see how it meets your requirements:

- **all be one program:** no cross-compiled binary I guess; but yes, the same product on all devices.
- **run on Windows 7, Android 4.0+, iOS 7+:** Yupp.
- **be under £20 altogether, no subscriptions:** £0 should be OK? *No signup or login required* to me implies it should be free to use as well.
- **be easy and simple:** Admitted, the OTK is an "extra step". But apart from that, it sounds "easy and simple", right?
- **be reliable:** I cannot argue from own experiences, so let me quote from a market comment:

> It does what it promises. It's a very efficient app. I have an ipad and a Galaxy s5 phone and always faced challenges tranfering stuff from one to the other. The easiest way was emailing, until a found Send anywhere. I gave it a 4 stars rating because it crashes once in a while, but I think that it's just when I try to transfer too many files at once. Anyway, it's definitely worth.

And it's the only one I'm aware of working on all the required platforms, apart from that. Some other candidates to check (I've not verified other than availability for Android, so I might have missed one) can be found in my app listing on [Filetransfer between two Android devices](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_misc#group_433).

Comment: will try it. The `because it crashes once in a while` kind of puts me off ;p, but i'll try it. +1 for great answer!

Comment: Thanks! I've explicitly let that part in to show it might not be "perfect". But that user also relativated it by saying it might be "somehow his fault" ;) Might not be intended to large amounts of files that is. But if you're rarely going for those "large amounts", it might well fit you. And count the "OTK" as the requested "abracadabra" (which btw is Hebrew: "I create with my words") :)

Comment: Wow... talk about general knowledge ;) I won't be transferring large amounts, so... we'll see :)

Comment: I just found that fitting, at least at the receiving end: "I just put 6 letters, and a file-rabbit comes out of my hat (and optionally brings its family along, ouch)" :) Literal translation would be "I create as I speak", and I need to check if it's Hebrew or Aramaic (the two are sometimes too close together), but nevermind. Enjoy the app, looking forward to your feedback (checkmark ;) // Yuck, right, it was aramaic: [Abracadabra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abracadabra)...

Comment: anyway... i've installed it on my windows computer, ipad, and android... It. Is. Perfect!!!!!!! No crashes so far. Brilliant app(s)! Thank you!!

Comment: \o/ Glad to read – enjoy the "powers of magic" :)

Comment: Great solution, only 2 minor defaults I've seen so far: code expires within 10 minutes and upload speed a bit slow (< 1 MB/s).